# Missing search scopes drop down

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, search-scope

I have restored a SharePoint site from one domain to another by content database backup and restore method.Site is working fine but it is missing search scopes. i did the same search configuration on this server as it was on original one.Site is showing only "All sites" scopes.

Comment: 'same search configuration'. Do you mean the scopes set up in the Search Service Application?

Comment: yes.same search setup in Search service Application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all.

I resolved the issue.
I went to central admin site->manage web application, then i selected my web application and clicked "service connection" from ribbon.
On service connection page, i made my newly created "search service application 1" as a default one.Now it is showing all the newly created scopes in "search scopes" and on site as well.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Site Settings > Search Scopes. You should see your scopes in here (if not you have bigger problems). Now click on Display Groups, and edit the display group Search Dropdown and add your scopes to the dropdown.

HTH